# Boot repair doesn't fix my grub boot after I repaired windows

Tags: boot, boot-repair

My system used to boot to Ubuntu 13.04 by default, preceded by the GRUB. I recently had a problem with Windows 8 (and do, pretty often, with Windows hanging at startup and refusing to shut down properly), so I had to run an automatic repair on Windows, which reconfigured the default boot to Windows. I, however find it easier to work with the Ubuntu GRUB as it gives me all boot options. So, I booted to Ubuntu again and ran Boot Repair (this usually works), but was surprised to find that the system was still booting to Windows as a default. I eventually discovered that the Boot Manager contained two images of Ubuntu (after the first Boot Repair). I was careless (and lazy) enough not to have noted down the pastebin link created after the first Boot Repair, but I ran the Boot Repair again, only to find that it didn't work at all. I, however, copied the pastebin link this time round (if it's of any consequence):

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7014774/.

Boot Info shows no boot loader in the MBR.
What can be done to remove the duplicate image and reconfigure GRUB as default? Any links?

Comment: let us discuss here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company .I will help you.

Comment: Follow this http://askubuntu.com/questions/424143/boot-repair-asking-for-64-bit-iso-what-do-i-do-with-it/424145#424145 answer.

Comment: Hi @Avinash Raj, thanks for your reply. I checked the link, but the problem indicated there is different to that of mine. My GRUB is still pretty much installed. The only issue (if we could call it that) is that it doesn't appear automatically at startup. When I direct myself to the Boot Manager by pressing the F9 key, the list shows two images/entries of Ubuntu along with that of Windows 8. So, in order to boot to Ubuntu, I have to specify which image/entry I want to boot from, after which the GRUB appears. If I don't do this, it boots automatically to Windows.