# Grub chainloader doesn't work with Windows 8

Tags: grub2, windows-8, uefi

What should I enter below to run Windows 8 from the Grub menu? I'm a total newbie, and it doesn't work from the beginning somehow.

Ubuntu works perfectly fine, but Windows gives me some error message like incorrect something (`Secure Boot forbids loading module` and `unknown command 'drivemap'`). I know I need to change something here to make it work, but I don't know what.

```
menuentry "Windows 8" {
set root = "(hd0,4)"

  chainloader +1

  }
```

I got a purple screen with this error message:

```
error: Secure Boot forbids loading module from (hd3, gpt0)/boot/grub/normal.mod.
error: no such device: 861287C9128786A9.
error: unknown command ‘drivemap’.
error: no such partition.

Press any key to continue..._
```

**Update:** I disabled Secure Boot, and again I got a purple screen with the following error message:

```
error: unknown command ‘drivemap’.
error: invalid EFI file path.

Press any key to continue..._
```

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/22632/202806) would help you.

Comment: I don't understand it.

Comment: I don't know what set root is supposed to be etc.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo os-prober`?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Could you please explain it to me clearly what I should do and what to focus on instead of giving me names I have no idea about.

Comment: Okay, I got this:
/dev/sdb2:Windows Recovery Environment (loader):Windows:chain

/dev/sdb4:Windows 8 (loader):Windows1:chain

Comment: I've got answer to your question @AvinashRaj

Comment: Now try `sudo update-grub` command.That's all.Now your windows entry will appear on the grub.

Comment: I've done that but it changes nothing. The problem is that I had Windows 8 loader in the grub from the beginning but it couldn't run properly. Just have a look at the problem:
http://imgur.com/cCaSnTl

Comment: I've also changed that hd gpt to the one that you see now because I thought this may work. Oh my god.

Comment: You mean windows entry appears on the grub but it fails to load.Am i correct?

Comment: I think so. It is on the list but just doesn't load Windows.

Comment: Any solutions? @AvinashRaj

Comment: What was the error message displayed while you click on Windows option in the grub?

Comment: Already gave you a link to a screenshot. Have a look http://imgur.com/cCaSnTl

Comment: Anything? @AvinashRaj

Comment: Disable secureboot in bios.And then try again.

Comment: There is just less text than previously. Same thing. Take a look: http://imgur.com/zz0UWtn

Comment: invalid efi path error, try this http://askubuntu.com/a/424145/202806 answer.

Comment: But this error was already there when I installed Ubuntu for the very first time. System didn't allow me to run Windows even straight after the installation. I've tried to repair boot many times and it just didn't work. @AvinashRaj

Comment: post the boot-repair log.

Comment: What's that? Where do I find it? First of all when I put the recovery files onto the USB and tried to run it everything went fine but when that blue windows 8 screen appeared when I was meant to click on troubleshoot I have noticed run USB flash drive or something like that while I've already booted the recovery from the USB. It's like a loop. I boot the system from the USB and when it goes to the troubleshoot screen I can click on the USB again and again and again. I can't really repair boot with this USB method or maybe I'm doing this wrong. @AvinashRaj

Comment: Everything is as on the very beginning. When I press 'e' to see the Windows 8 details in grub, everything is after I've installed the system. All I need is the correct details to put into there so the Windows could finally run. I think that the boot has been repaired but some incorrect details are being stored in the boot repair thingy.

Comment: Searching for `drivemap` should have brought your to http://askubuntu.com/q/233687/40581 without the Boot-Repair bogus. :) If your partition table is not GPT but MBR, then you might want to look at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/q/447686/40581 it deals with MBR installations and creates a new separate boot configuration, though this is intended for using more than one hard drive and requires a bootable Windows installation (I haven't tried running bcdboot with wine yet).

Answer (score 1):

```
menuentry "Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)" --class windows8 --class os {
        insmod ntfs
        set root='(hdo,2)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 5e32cd5e32cd3bb1
        drivemap -s (hD0) ${root}
        chainloader +1
}
```

Comment: That probably won't work as the `drivemap` commmand is missing for UEFI installations.