# How to boot Windows 8 from a legacy MBR partition in UEFI mode via GRUB?

Tags: windows-8, uefi, grub-efi

This question is similar to the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/235519/40581) 
of [Dual-boot Ubuntu 12.10 on UEFI along Windows 8 (GRUB - error: can't find command drivemap)](https://askubuntu.com/q/233687/40581), but Windows 8 is installed on a **legacy partitioned drive**.

What steps need to be performed to make the installation boot in UEFI mode without converting to GPT or using DISM?

<sup>I know that it is generally [not recommended](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) to mix UEFI and legacy booting, but it can be handy in some setups.</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to boot Windows 8 in UEFI mode, even if you installed it on a legacy partitioned disk (MS-DOS/MBR). Of course you would need a UEFI compatible GRUB installation on another GPT partitioned disk.

1. In Windows, **install a new boot configuration to volume C:** by running the following command:

   ```
   bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f uefi
   ```

   When booted in UEFI mode this will not only create a new boot configuration in `C:\EFI\` but also register a new UEFI bootloader in NVRAM. You can remove the entry later with `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu (for instructions see: [How do I remove "Ubuntu" in the bios boot menu? (UEFI)](https://askubuntu.com/q/63610/40581)).

   Of course you can also choose another location, but this method should be the easiest. For more details on `bcdboot` see the corresponding [Microsoft Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824874.aspx).
2. In Ubuntu, add a **custom GRUB menu entry** by adding the following lines to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

   ```
   menuentry "Windows 8 (BCD-UEFI configuration on system drive /dev/sda2)" --class windows --class os {
       insmod part_msdos
       insmod ntfs
       insmod search_fs_uuid
       insmod chain

       set root='hd0,msdos2'
       if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  2ACC7043CC700B79
       else
         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2ACC7043CC700B79
       fi

       chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
   }
   ```

   Note that you will need to **edit** the following parameters **if your configuration differs**:

   - This entry is configured to boot from the 2nd partition (`msdos2`) of the 1st hard drive (`hd0` or `ahci0`).
   - You also need to replace the filesystem UUID (`2ACC7043CC700B79`) with yours. In this example you could run `sudo blkid /dev/sda2` to get the UUID or start GParted.
   - Reminder: This example deals with a drive that has a legacy partition table. If yours is GPT, then replace `msdos` with `gpt`.
3. Finally run `sudo update-grub` to generate the new configuration.

<sup>Answer moved from https://askubuntu.com/q/377807/40581 as it looked out of place there.</sup>

Comment: The custom GRUB entry isn't needed (at least not for windows 10's boot manager), you can install to the BCD to your main EFI partition, with "bcdboot C:\Windows /s X: /f UEFI", where X is the letter you assigned to the UEFI partition. You can assign a letter to the UEFI partition either using the windows gui or using "diskpart" command line utility. This works even if windows isn't in a GPT partition.

Comment: Wow, this one `bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f uefi` is only what worked for me. Other answers suggest to reinstall Windows. Btw menu entry works with only `search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2ACC7043CC700B79` and `chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` other lines is not necessary.

Comment: Note that if you are on windows 7, the /f option may not be there. I downloaded bcdboot.exe from Windows 8 online and run the command from the downloaded exe. It worked.

Comment: the hardest thing I has been passed because you bro!