# Boot-repair: "You have to give the partition where EFI files are located."

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit, uefi, boot-repair

I'm using the 64 bit ISO of Boot-repair to deal with UEFI. I followed [Boot repair asking for 64 bit iso - what do I do with it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424143/boot-repair-asking-for-64-bit-iso-what-do-i-do-with-it) and I was able to do almost everything in it. I'm stumped at this point:

> You have to give the partition where EFI files are located.

When I go to Advanced Options, I see nothing resembling those instructions.

Assuming that I'm just doing it wrong, could someone please walk me through that particular subset of instructions?

Answer (score 0):

## Have multiple /boot/efi partitions?

If so, don't use boot repair, instead follow these instructions:

Find the `/boot/efi` partition for Windows using `fdisk -l|grep EFI` and select the 260 MB one. Remember the partition number, for example `2` for `/dev/sda2`.

In `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` paste this:

```
menuentry 'Microsoft Windows 8' {
set root='hd0,gpt2'
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
boot
}
```

The line `set root` might need to be changed to match your partition number.
For example `set root='hd0,gpt4'` for partition number `4`.

Reboot and boot into Windows.

Comment: fdisk does not work on gpt partitioned drives which is used for UEFI boot. Use parted or gdisk to list partitions and the FAT32 one will be the efi partition if otherwise correctly configured. sudo parted -l or sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda

Comment: oldfred's advice worked. But I only found one EFI. None of the code suggested by lolzies worked. In fact, I got errors concerning Python.

Also, in a stroke of genius, I forgot to mention that I'm trying to dual boot 13.04 with Windows 7.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was Win8. :(